# AS608 Optical Fingerprint Sensor With Raspberry PI is not waiting for finger input

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, fingerprint

I'm trying to connect Fingerprint (AS608) sensor with Raspberry PI 3 B+.

`finger.get_image()` function is not waiting to put finger on sensor. returning 0x0 automatically.

used ttyUSB0 port.

I'm referring source code here https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_Fingerprint/blob/main/examples/fingerprint_simpletest.py

Let me know what I'm missing ?

Thanks in advance.